# Como instanciar um vetor

Tags: java, array

Estou fazendo um programa (trabalho de faculdade), e estou com dificuldade em instanciar um vetor.

Além disso ele está apresentando alguns erros que eu não estou conseguindo resolver - um deles é no laço `while`, no fechamento da classe principal.

> Como instancio esse vetor e como elimino os outros erros?

**Enunciado do trabalho:**

Faça um programa Java para criar um cadastro de funcionários.
Solicite ao usuário o número de funcionários da empresa, para dimensionar os vetores.

Exiba um menu com as seguintes opções:

1 - CADASTRAR FUNCIONÁRIO
2 - CONSULTAR FUNCIONÁRIO
3 - LISTAR TODOS FUNCIONÁRIOS
4 - LISTAR SOMENTE FUNCIONÁRIOS ATIVOS
5 - LISTAR FUNCIONÁRIOS EM ORDEM DE IDADE CRESCENTE
10 - SAIR

O cadastro de funcionários deve conter as seguintes informações:

NOME, IDADE, SITUAÇÃO (ativo/inativo)

As listas devem exibir sempre todas as informações do funcionário.

> Classe Funcionário:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Funcionarios {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private String situacao;
    private int quantidade[];

    public Funcionarios() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Funcionarios [quantidade=" + Arrays.toString(quantidade) + "]";
    }

    public Funcionarios(String nome, int idade, String situacao){
            this.nome=nome;
            this.idade=idade;
            this.situacao=situacao;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome){
            this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade){
            this.idade = idade;
    }

    public void setSituacao(String situacao){
            this.situacao = situacao;
    }

    public String getNome(){
            return nome.toUpperCase();
    }

    public int getIdade(){
            return idade;
    }

    public String getSituacao(){
            return situacao.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

> Classe Menu:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Menu{

    private List<Funcionarios> listaF = new ArrayList<>();


    public Menu() {

    }

    public Menu(List<Funcionarios> listaF){
        this.listaF=listaF;
    }

    public void addFuncionario(String nome, int idade, String situacao){
        Funcionarios f = new Funcionarios(nome, idade, situacao);
        listaF.add(f);
    }
    public void addFunc(Funcionarios f){
        listaF.add(f);
    }

    public void consultar(String nome){
        for(int i = 0; i< listaF.size(); i++){
            if(listaF.get(i).getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(nome)){
                System.out.println("Nome: "+listaF.get(i).getNome());
                System.out.println("Idade: "+listaF.get(i).getIdade());
                System.out.println("Situacao: "+listaF.get(i).getSituacao());
            }
        }
    }
    public void consulta(Menu listagem){
        listaF.get(0);
    }

    public void listaCompleta(){
        if(listaF != null){
            for(int i = 0; i< listaF.size(); i++){
                System.out.println("Nome: "+listaF.get(i).getNome());
                System.out.println("Idade: "+listaF.get(i).getIdade());
                System.out.println("Situacao: "+listaF.get(i).getSituacao());
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Banco de dados vazio, necessário cadastrar funcionários");
        }
    }

    public void listaAtivos(){
        for(int i = 0; i< listaF.size(); i++){
            if(listaF.get(i).getSituacao().equalsIgnoreCase("ativo")){
                System.out.println("Nome: "+listaF.get(i).getNome());
                System.out.println("Idade: "+listaF.get(i).getIdade());
                System.out.println("Situacao: "+listaF.get(i).getSituacao());
            }
        }
    }

    public void listaPorIdades(){
        List<Funcionarios> listaPorIdade = listaF.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Funcionarios::getIdade))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(int i = 0; i< listaPorIdade.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Nome: " + listaPorIdade.get(i).getNome());
            System.out.println("Idade: " + listaPorIdade.get(i).getIdade());
            System.out.println("Situacao: " + listaPorIdade.get(i).getSituacao());
        }
    }
}
```

> Classe Principal:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SistemaProva {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        Menu m = new Menu();

        String nome;
        int idade;
        String situacao;
        int op;

        System.out.println("Bem-Vindo(a) ao Sistema");
        do{
            System.out.println("\n\tMenu\n\n");
            System.out.println("Digite a opção desejada:\n1: 1-Cadastrar Funcionário\n2: 2-Consultar Funcionário\n3: 3-Listagem Completa de Funcionários\n4: 4-Listagem de Funcionários Ativos\n5: 5-Listagem de Funcionários por Idade\n0: 10-Sair\n");
            op=ler.nextInt();

        if(op==1){
            //int quantidade;
                System.out.println("Quantos funcionários tem na empresa?");
                int quantidade[] = new int[quantidade];
                //quantidade[quantidade] = quantidade;
                for (int i = 0; i < quantidade.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("\n\tCadastrar Funcionário:\n");
                    System.out.println("Nome: ");
                    try{
                        nome=ler.next();
                        System.out.println("Idade: ");
                        idade=ler.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Situacao(Ativo ou Inativo): ");
                        situacao=ler.next();
                        m.addFuncionario(nome, idade, situacao);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Erro encontrado! Refaça!");
                        }
                    }
                }


        if(op==2){
            System.out.println("\n\tConsultar Funcionário:\n");
            System.out.println("Qual o nome do funcionário que deseja consultar? ");
            try{
            nome=ler.next();
            m.consultar(nome);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Erro encontrado! Refaça ou primeiro cadastre funcionários!");
        }

        if(op==3){
            System.out.println("\n\tListagem Completa de Funcionário:\n");
            m.listaCompleta();
        }

        if(op==4){
            System.out.println("\n\tListagem de Funcionários Ativos:\n");
            m.listaAtivos();
        }

        if(op==5){
            System.out.println("\n\tListagem de Funcionário por Idade:\n");
            m.listaPorIdades();
        }

        if(op==10){
            System.out.printf("\nEncerrando Sistema!");
        }

        }while(op!=0);

        ler.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No opção de menu 1-Cadastrar Funcionário a definição da quantidade:

```
int quantidade[] = new int[quantidade];
```

Tem de ser:

```
int quantidade = ler.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) { //alterado também
```

Para ler o valor da consola, uma vez que é so a quantidade de funcionários que se vai ler pelo `for`. Por esse motivo não precisa de ser um vetor.

Na mesma classe este `catch`:

```
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Erro encontrado! Refaça ou primeiro cadastre funcionários!");
```

Não tem a chaveta de fecho, e deveria então ser:

```
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Erro encontrado! Refaça ou primeiro cadastre funcionários!");
}
```